# WHMCS payment getwayconfig page blank while setup new gateway Instamojo

Tags: php, plugins, payment, whmcs, instamojo

i develop WHMCS payment plugin using Instamojo (payment getway service provider)

but when i try to setup it on WHMCS, that time paymentgetwayconfig  page become totally white (Blank page).

Here is payment getway module that i develop,
please check here is download link: 
[Click Here To Download Plugin File.](http://www.kmwebsoft.com/free-zone/WHMCS-Instamjo-Plugin.zip)

Comment: Accept answer if your issue has been solved

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to enable error reporting by configuration.php file.

The lines needs to be added at the very end of the configuration.php file, right before the closing PHP tag ?> if your configuration.php file has one, otherwise just the last line in the file.

```
$display_errors = true;
$display_errors = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE;
```

After adding the lines and saving/uploading the file, retry the steps that previously led to the blank or partially rendered page and further error information should be displayed.

Refer: http://docs.whmcs.com/Provisioning_Module_Developer_Docs

i have also developed same plugin for whmcs, soon i will publish it github because many people want same plugin so i decided to publish it at this git location:https://github.com/shivsingh7150/whmcs-Instamojo-payment-gateway

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
i check your developed plugin, but there is no any callback file ?

Instamojo now support new API, is your developed plugin with this new API ? or Old ?

can you tell me which file i put into getway folder of whmcs and which into folder Callback ?  from your plugin for testing purpose.

Comment: @Mr.KirtiJoshi thaank for update me, now i have added call directory and file also. you can check updated git, and this new API that support auto invoice paid.

Comment: i try your github plugin, but its not working for me,
is it working at your end ?
can you reupload for me - just working files  like  main getway folder file and callback folder file,  i'm thankful to you, for your great help. :)

Comment: Here is my working Instamojo files, but its not update invoice status after successful payment, can you check php files and fix it with new API ?

[Click Here Download Instamojo Module](http://www.kmwebsoft.com/free-zone/Instamojo(2).zip)

Its run perfect, but every time i need to add payment manually on client's invoice. i hope have you some solution for this.

Comment: @Mr.KirtiJoshi ji i have already added callback file and same is working fine on my end. you should check it again and don't forget to enter Salt and key from back end of WHMCS